# как сделать группировку по дням mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите с запросом:

```
SELECT DateTimeOp, SUM(Mass) 
FROM DataScales 
WHERE (DateTimeOp BETWEEN '2018.11.17 00:00' AND '2018.11.30 13:55')  
GROUP BY DAY(DateTimeOp)
```

мне нужно чтобы выводилось 2 колонки: дата и суммамассы.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - а сейчас сколько выводится?

Comment: выдается ошибка, а вот если я делаю так:
    `код SELECT SUM(Mass) 
    FROM DataScales 
    WHERE (DateTimeOp BETWEEN '2018.11.17 00:00' AND '2018.11.30 13:55')  
    GROUP BY DAY(DateTimeOp)`
то все работает, но мне нужно чтобы выводилась колонка с датой

Comment: SELECT DAY(DateTimeOp) ... GROUP BY DAY(DateTimeOp)

Comment: *нужно чтобы выводилась колонка с датой* Ну так и выводите именно дату. *выдается ошибка* Ошибки принято цитировать (впрочем, тут и так понятно, что за ошибка - и, кстати, она поясняет, в чём косяк).

Comment: спасибо, Okdel, все получилось!

Comment: Не за что. Но лучше запостить получившийся запрос, чтоб остальным было видно что нужно сделать.